# Locally cloned repository not syncing

Tags: git

I have a .git repository and when a clone it, its not syncing. When i run "git branch", i'm receiving the branch "master", but that it's not sync when i make changes in the original project folder.

how can i sync the master branch in another directory?

My directory tree:

```
folder
 |_ Project
 |    |_ .git
 |
 |_ Another Folder 
 |    |_ Project
 |         |_ .git
```

commands that i runed:

```
PS c:Another Folder>: git clone "c:Project/.git"
```

Comment: you just need to run `git fetch` or `git pull` from your clone. Your clone will see the first repo as a regular remote.

Comment: Did you run `git pull` or `git fetch` as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating local Git repo with another local repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778533/updating-local-git-repo-with-another-local-repo)

Comment: im receiving "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): 
.git"

Comment: Im go to take a look on this, thanks Inigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cloning a remote (or local) repository, it must be setup as "bare". Without this initial condition you can't clone from it.

In order to clone from a local repository, you can use the following command: `git clone --local {path-to-repo}`. This will create a clone which you can use for regular git tasks (add, rebase, merge, push, etc.).

Note that you can also convert an existing regular (cloned) repository to a bare repository for cloning with `git config --bool core.bare true`.

EDIT:

As pointed out in the comment section (@LeGEC), you actually can clone from a non bare repo. However, you will not be able to issue `git push` commands on the checked out branch.

Comment: needs fixing: you can perfectly clone a non bare repo. The only limitation of using a non bare repo as a remote is that git will refuse to accept `git push` commands that would update the active branch of that repo -- e.g: if checked out branch in the non bare remote is `master`, you won't be able to run `git push` on the `master` branch from the clone.

Comment: @LeGEC Thanks for pointing that out, I updated the answer accordinlgly