# Merge a branch into fresh repository

Tags: git, github, git-merge

Let's say where I have a git branch like this `sampath-test`. I created this branch from the `master repo`. I have created another fresh repository (`master`) like `ionic3-refactored`. This new `master` repository only has a readme file. So could you tell me how can I merge `sampath-test` code to fresh `master` repo `ionic3-refactored`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-to-clone-a-single-branch-in-git maybe, although I don't really understand what you're trying to do

Comment: The link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21353656/merge-git-repo-into-branch-of-another-repo/21353836 should be helpful in your case.

Comment: I have added more content. Please see that too @Mat

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) to do this.

```
git push <path to repository> <local branch name>:<remote branch name>
```

Here's an example.

First, here's the source repository. The `master` branch has a few files and the `branch1` branch has an additional file:

```
$ git branch
  branch1
* master

$ ls
file1.txt  file2.txt  README

$ git log | grep -v Author
commit 56cd34350e846b92762d16af1c777ff4075fff3e
Date:   Sun Jun 10 01:02:23 2018 -0700

    Add file1.txt and file2.txt

commit c5d453a847d3b61b75f8a27de3b3cdc163421398
Date:   Sun Jun 10 01:01:55 2018 -0700

    Add README

$ git checkout branch1
Switched to branch 'branch1'

$ ls
file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt  README

$ git log | grep -v Author
commit bbdbd16488f835ee9bd0903274e45d18b0e621a1
Date:   Sun Jun 10 01:02:53 2018 -0700

    Add file3.txt

commit 56cd34350e846b92762d16af1c777ff4075fff3e
Date:   Sun Jun 10 01:02:23 2018 -0700

    Add file1.txt and file2.txt

commit c5d453a847d3b61b75f8a27de3b3cdc163421398
Date:   Sun Jun 10 01:01:55 2018 -0700

    Add README
```

Here's creating a new repository and pushing `newbranch` into it along with it's history:

```
$ mkdir ../newrepo

$ cd ../newrepo/

$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/chuckx/code/stackoverflow/gitpush/newrepo/.git/

$ cd ../repo1/

$ git push ../newrepo/ branch1:newbranch1
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 596 bytes | 596.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../newrepo/
 * [new branch]      branch1 -> newbranch1

$ cd ../newrepo/

$ git branch
  newbranch1

$ ls

$ git checkout newbranch1
Switched to branch 'newbranch1'

$ ls
file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt  README

$ git log | grep -v Author
commit bbdbd16488f835ee9bd0903274e45d18b0e621a1
Date:   Sun Jun 10 01:02:53 2018 -0700

    Add file3.txt

commit 56cd34350e846b92762d16af1c777ff4075fff3e
Date:   Sun Jun 10 01:02:23 2018 -0700

    Add file1.txt and file2.txt

commit c5d453a847d3b61b75f8a27de3b3cdc163421398
Date:   Sun Jun 10 01:01:55 2018 -0700

    Add README
```