# Merge a git repository into another

Tags: git

How to merge a git repository into another repository. Note that I do not want to create a third repository with merged code neither want to add as a subdirectory. Instead, I want to merge one into the other as a combined repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge git repo into branch of another repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21353656/merge-git-repo-into-branch-of-another-repo)

Answer (score 0):

Git repositories are a collection of graphs. You haven't told us how the two graphs relate in your case. But either way, you can simply add the one as a remote to the other, and *fetch* its contents. At this point you will have all commits from both repositories. Then you figure out how you want to merge the two graphs.