# git rebase a floating branch

Tags: git, rebase

I have imported another repo as a branch based on solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21353656/14039503).

Now, the new imported branch is floated while it should be connect the way specified in the image.

How should I do the rebase?

```
git checkout imported-branch
git rebase ????? --onto ????
```

[image: git rebase]

Comment: What is the relation between `f8114a` and `d0ece` ? for example : do you know for a fact that the content of `f8114a`is exactly the same as the content of `d0ece` ?

Comment: @LeGEC, they might be the same or with minimum changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get what you've drawn, because you drew in commit hash IDs: `f8114a` for instance.  Given that `f8114a` is drawn as a root commit, this means that `f8114a` is *always* a root commit, in the past, present, and forever in the future too.  But in the right hand side of the drawing, `f8114a` is *not* a root commit: it has a parent `d0ece`.  So you've claimed that `f8114a` is both a root commit (no parents) and a regular everyday commit (one parent, `d0ece`), and this is simply not possible.

You may be able to get what you *want*.  This depends on precisely what it is that you do want.  Trying to do this with `git rebase` is usually a bad idea, though: if there are any branch-and-merge operations in the set of commits you're trying to graft onto one of *your* branches, rebase itself will have to re-perform any of the merges involved, and that's a recipe for breaking stuff.

Now, remember that any commit, whatever its hash ID might be, and whatever parent hash IDs it might have, represents a *full and complete snapshot* of the files that are contained inside that commit.  So commit `f8114a` *is* a snapshot.  Since it it has no parent (on the left side), Git will *show* it as a comparison against a pseudo-commit that has no files.<sup>1</sup>  So `f8114a` consists of *add all of its files*, when viewed as a set of changes.

If you take `f8114a` and copy it to a new-and-¿improved? commit—let's call this `f9114a`, although the actual hash ID will probably be different, but we need to have *something* to call it<sup>2</sup>—that *does* have a parent commit, though, now `git show` and other Git operations that compare the copy against its parent *will* have a snapshot to compare against.  So now, instead of *add all of these files*, the diff may say *delete most of the files, and create these mostly new ones instead, then change a whole lot of a few remaining files*.

If that's OK with you, it's easy to get this to happen in *your own* repository, without having it happen in any clones anyone makes *of* your repository.  Just use `git replace` with the `--graft` option.  See [the `git replace` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace) for details.

Once you're satisfied with some replacement(s), you can use a no-op `git filter-repo` (or the old but still supported, and included with Git distributions, `git filter-branch`) to rewrite commits reachable from the tip of `imported-branch`.  This will "cement the replacement in place" and allow you to discard the graft; cloning this filtered repository will produce a copy of the filtered repository, which no longer uses the replacement trick.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically Git uses the [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452) to fake up this pseudo-commit.  It diffs your commit's tree against the empty tree to produce all the "add entire file" diff-hunks.

<sup>2</sup>Call it Fred or Barney or Wilma if you like; [just don't call it late for dinner.](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/66205/180540)