# How to consolidate multiple GIT repos under one new repo

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-submodules

I have multiple repos always with only `master` branch. Lets call them `repoA/master`, `repoB/master`, `repoC/master`. Now I would like create new repo `newRepo` that would have branches: repoA, repoB, repoC...

Then I would like to copy `repoA/master` to `newRepo/repoA`, `repoB/master` to `newRepo/repoB`, `repoC/master` to `newRepo/repoC`. Finally, I want to delete `repoA`,  `repoB`,  `repoC`. This way, I will have previously 3 separated repos in one.

Potentially `submodule` could do it? But what would happen if the origin repo would get deleted?
Thank you!

EDIT: Based on the comment section I should have specified that the goal is also to keep commit history for each repo.

Comment: Submodules are not branches, they **are** separate repositories. They require separate remote repositories if you ever would want to publish your superproject to colleagues or the general public.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Comment: I think the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10548919/14956277) in the dupe target I linked covers merging repositories.

Comment: Can you clarify what you’re trying to achieve by doing this? Why wouldn’t you just push the master branch of each repo to a new repo with a different branch name? I can give instructions for this, if that’s what you’re asking for. Or why wouldn’t you just have a folder for each repo in one repo?

Comment: Do you want to keep the history of the original repos or just start the branches in newrepo with the current contents of the original repos?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers. I edited my question -> I want to keep commit history for each repo.

Actually, I was trying similar steps as suggested by @DM in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories/10548919#10548919). 

I was following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21353656/merge-git-repo-into-branch-of-another-repo/21353836), but during 2nd repo git wanted to merge all files despite having 2 branches already. Maybe it was because I didn't remove 1st remote repo?