# How can merge folder(only one,not all) from one repository to second?

Tags: git

I have two repositories.In A repository i added one folder from B repository.But now i have some changes in this folder in B repository.How i can added changes from B repo from only one folder?
I did `git fetch git://repository.url/repo.git master:folder_name` but it's added all folders

Comment: That isn't relative to Java, even if java is the language of the code in the folders, it could python or C, that would be same

Comment: Yes, you are right, I added java automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two options:

A) Create a patch from `repo_b` and apply it to `repo_a` (easier).

B) Add `repo_b` as a remote of `repo_a` and [merge unrelated histories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21353836/1256234). (more complicated).

Here's how you do option A:

```
cd repo_b
git whatchanged --reverse folder_name
git diff deadb33f HEAD > folder.patch
```

Above you are determining the point in `repo_b`'s history, where, from that point onwards you want to get all the changes.  That commit should be `deadb33f`.

```
cd repo_a
git checkout -b new_branch
git reset --hard decafbad
```

Where `decafbad` is the commit where the two repos diverged.

```
patch -p1 < folder.patch
git add changed_folder
git commit -m "changes from repo_b"
```

This will, however, squash all the changes into one commit.  If you want to keep the commit history from `repo_b`, go with the method I linked to above (option B).

Comment: When i try to do **git diff 3a4c9aa0f7ed84e04618ae8c936d4adeb2653a80 HEAD > absolute_path_folder** i have the issue - **Access is denied**.

Comment: Could you paste the entire error message here?  Are you using git on linux natively, or via mingw (or similar) on Windows?  If you're working with a local copy of the git repo, the .git directory and all checked-out files should by owned by your username and group.  You can check that with `ls -la`.

Comment: I changed cmd on Git Bash -                                                                                        
`$ git diff b3c5a1032b07bfb3f3e61023c793c579089223e5 HEAD > "..\repob\folder_name"
                                                                                                                                  
 bash: …\folder_name: Is a directory   `
It seems to me that this is not the behavior that should be

Comment: The syntax is `git diff b3c5a1032b0 HEAD > name.patch` where name.patch is the patch file you are creating from `repo_b`.

Comment: `$ patch -p1 < "C:\ name.patch"
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/…/Myclass.java b/MySecondClass.java
|index 071c8d950..15eb7f763 100644
|--- a/ Myclass.java.java
|+++ b/ MySecondClass.java
--------------------------
File to patch:
`  
I don't understand what should I do next?

Comment: It sounds like you're missing a bit of background on git patches.  I think [this blog post](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/03/git-patch-create-and-apply) has a pretty good summary.  The only difference is they're using `git patch` instead of `patch`, but the result is the same.  By the time you're done reading it you should be good generating and applying patches.